# Full URI to a file on another machine in our local network?

Tags: file-sharing, path, ip-address, url, uri

On our small-business Windows XP network, I have a file in f:\MyDir\SubDir\text.doc

What would be the URI for that file while I'm on another machine.... if all I knew was that machine's IP address, and the file's path?

I thought it was something like:

```
\\192.168.10.20\f:\MyDir\SubDir\text.doc
```

But that can't seem to locate it.  (I have full admin access to both machines)

Answer (score 5):

Usually, you have to specifically share the folder over the network.

If you have Administrator rights on the remote computer, you can access *fixed* disks (not removable ones) through the predefined "administrative shares", named `<letter>$`. For example:

```
\\192.168.10.20\f$\MyDir\SubDir\text.doc
```

---

Second, the `\\<host>\<share>\<path>` format is an *UNC path*. If you really need an *URI*, it will likely look like this:

```
file://192.168.10.20/f$/MyDir/SubDir/text.doc
```

or:

```
smb://192.168.10.20/f$/MyDir/SubDir/text.doc
```

Answer (score 1):

Close, switch the colon to a dollar sign.

```
\\192.168.10.20\f$\MyDir\SubDir\text.doc
```

Assuming domain--I've not tested on workgroups.

Answer (score 0):

For UNC: 
If you create a share from MyDir, omit the drive letter when accessing it remotely: \ip-address\sharename\subdir...

To use the administrative F$ share, be sure to use (remote computername)\administrator as the login (or it will try and fail to use the local admin token)